# Posting form data efficiently to two pages

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am working in a classic ASP project where the flow was like this:

> a ---->  b ------>  c

and another flow was like this:

> a  ------>  d   -------> c

but now, due to a change in requirements, the flow needs to be like this:

> a  ----->  b  -----> d  ------> c

The form data which was previously posted to page `d` now needs to be posted to page `b`. Is there any way to post this data again from `b` to `d`?

I have kept those values in a session in `b.asp` but, in that case, I have to change the existing design in page `d` since `request.form()` is used to read those.

Is there any better way to do this without changing the design in page `d`? Can the form variables posted in `b` be again posted in `d`?

Comment: Why did you add the php tag?

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic thanks for reading my post. I think Php and asp classic has some similarities like posting and reading form data. May be the solution for the above problem would be same for both. Thats why I added the tag.

Comment: @Don'tPanic . If you know the solution for the php version of this problem , can you please answer ? It will be same for asp classic.

Comment: In PHP, another way to handle this if you don't want the values to be stored in the session is to put the posted values into hidden inputs in a form on the intermediate page.

Comment: @Don'tPanic. Excellent. I will try this one. If this works, this will be great as this will not break the design in page d. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In page B, create a `<form>` and write the session values to `<hidden>` form elements. I'm not sure how your `b.asp` page functions, but you can write the form on the initial page load or a post-back and have it submit automatically or you could have a client action submit the form.

For example, to create a page that just forwards the POST to `d.asp`:

```vb
Response.Clear
Response.Write "<html>"
Response.Write "<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>"
Response.Write "<form name='form' action='d.asp' method='post'>"

' For each Session variable...
Response.Write "<input type='hidden' name='SomeVar' value='" & Session("SomeVar") & "'>"

' Or, for each Form variable...
Response.Write "<input type='hidden' name='SomeVar' value='" & Request.Form("SomeVar") & "'>"

Response.Write "</form></body></html>"
Response.End
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to pass session variables from one page to another in this manner.

Comment: @Paul I don't think you understand the OP's question. His page is expected the values via a POST.

Comment: I see.  Yes, my apologies.